# How to implement the "JS's require" function in the perl's JE engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, perl

The [JE](https://metacpan.org/pod/JE) is an nice JavaScript engine written in pure perl. Perfectly executes common JS code a his ability bind perl subroutines to JS functions is wonderful.

What is missing the `require` function, what is implemented in the "node.js", and does similar task as the perl's require.

Would be nice to know, how to implement such function in perl and bind it to JE, e.g. in the simple skeleton:

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

use JE::Destroyer;
use JE;

my $jslib = path("./jslib");

my $j = new JE;
$j->new_function("say", sub { say @_ });  # the "say" in the JS
$j->new_function("require", sub {         # the "require"

    my $source = $jslib->child($_[0])->slurp_utf8; #read the source from some file
    #how to implement the require ?
    #e.g. what JE object should be created and what to bind to it?

});
```

Any idea how the `node.js`'s `require` function is implemented in C, and how to implement the same in perl?

### EDIT

For the more precise example adding an more extended skeleton:

- file `./reqtest.js` (the main program)

```
console.log("start");
p = require('adder');
console.log(p.add(2,3));
```

- file `./node_modules/adder.js` (in the "node_modules" - for the `node.js` test)

```
exports.add = function() {
    var sum = 0, i = 0, args = arguments, l = args.length;
    while (i < l) {
        sum += args[i++];
    }
    return sum;
};
```

running the above as

```
node reqtest.js
```

prints

```
start
5
```

so, it correctly required the `adder.js` and returned the object, but
running it with the following perl/JE script:

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;
use JE::Destroyer;
use JE;
use Scalar::Util qw( weaken );
use Path::Tiny;
use PIR;

my $script = path("reqtest.js")->slurp_utf8;

my $j = new JE;
$j->{console} = {};
$j->{console}->new_function("log", sub { say @_ });
{
    weaken(my $j = $j);
    $j->new_function(require => sub {
        my $source = get_source($_[0]);
        $j->eval($source) if $source;
    });
}

$j->eval($script);#eval the main script

JE::Destroyer::destroy($j);
undef $j;

#extremelly simplyfied
sub get_source {
    my $name = shift;
    return path("node_modules")->child("$name.js")->slurp_utf8;
}
```

prints only:

```
start
```

so, the "simple `$j->eval($source)` implementation of the `require` doesn't follows the `CommonJS` module specification - it needs *something* more.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, what is your use case? I would never imagine trying to use a JavaScript engine written in Perl for anything less trivial than "whoa! it works!" but then my imagination is rather limited. :)

Comment: @Alex Tokarev, Scrapping of pages generated using JS

Comment: @ikegami: If that's your use-case then you don't need the `require()` function which exists only in the server. Javascript from web pages cannot use the `require` function because it's not implemented in browsers.

Comment: @Alex Tokarev, You're confusing me with the OP, and you said you couldn't imagine any use case, so I gave one (that's not necessarily the OP's).

Comment: @ikegami: HA! And you're confusing me with Alex Tokarev

Comment: @slebetman, OMG LOL!

Comment: @ikegami Interesting. If I'm getting it right, you're essentially trying to run scrapped JavaScript in Perl simulator to get the resulting HTML? Doesn't that lead to DOM API simulation as well? Ouch, I'd rather use a headless browser for something like that...

Comment: Running webpage javascript in a javascript perl implementation might be a huge security problem for you, but more importantly running javascript in a javascript perl implementation is almost certainly the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @AndyRay JE is in same position as any interpreted templating languages like [Django](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dotiac::DTL) or [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) or anything what is more complex as simple tag substitution and allows cycles, conditionals and so on. Or if you want, it is like [any interpreter](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/interpreter)  written **in** JavaScript. It is simply an language what is interpreted with perl, and the perl **is** the right tool for such problems and does the right job.

Answer (score 1):

After a studying a bit, I created a following, (an extremely simplified) solution:

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;
use JE::Destroyer;
use JE;
use Scalar::Util qw( weaken );
use Path::Tiny;

my $script = path("reqtest.js")->slurp_utf8;

my $j = new JE;
$j->{console} = {};
$j->{console}->new_function("log", sub { say @_ });
{
    weaken(my $j = $j);   #based on ikegami's previous answer
    $j->new_function(require => sub {
        my $source = get_source($_[0]);
        my $code = new JE::Object::Function $j, qw(exports), $source;
        my $exports = $j->{Object};
        $code->($exports);
        return $exports;
    });
}

$j->eval($script);#eval the main script

JE::Destroyer::destroy($j);
undef $j;

# extremelly simplyfied code search
# the real code-search for the requide("some") should try the following
# some.js some/index.js some.json some/index.json
# for the defined search-paths.
sub get_source {
    my $name = shift;
    return path("node_modules")->child("$name.js")->slurp_utf8;
}
```

The above is an shortest possible implementation of the CommonJS require, and prints the same as the `node.js` for the example in the question

```
start
5
```

Of course, need many additional work (e.g. code caching) a like, but the minimal skeleton works.

Answer (score 0):

To execute `require.js`, you can use

```
my $require_js = get('http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.18/comments/require.js');

$j->eval($require_js);
```

Comment: You hadn't mentioned anything about wanting `require` returning an object. What object to you want it to return?

Comment: JS doesn't have a `require` function. What inputs and outputs do you want *your* function to have?

Comment: That's really different than what you originally asked, but if you want to run CommonJS's `require.js`, pass it to `eval`. Updated my answer.